# java.nio transferTo seems to be impossibly fast?

Tags: java, nio

Can someone please explain how the `transferTo` method can copy a file at seemingly 1000+ MB/sec.  I ran some tests using a 372MB binary file and the first copy is slow, but if I change the output name and run it again, an additional file appears in the output directory in as little as 180ms, which works out to over 2000 MB/sec.  What's going on here?  I'm running Windows 7.

```
private static void doCopyNIO(String inFile, String outFile) {
    FileInputStream     fis = null;
    FileOutputStream    fos = null;
    FileChannel         cis = null;
    FileChannel         cos = null;

    long                len = 0, pos = 0;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        cis = fis.getChannel();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        cos = fos.getChannel();
        len = cis.size();
        while (pos < len) {
            pos += cis.transferTo(pos, (1024 * 1024 * 10), cos);    // 10M
        }
        fos.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (cos != null) { try { cos.close(); } catch (Exception e) { } }
        if (fos != null) { try { fos.close(); } catch (Exception e) { } }
        if (cis != null) { try { cis.close(); } catch (Exception e) { } }
        if (fis != null) { try { fis.close(); } catch (Exception e) { } }
    }
}
```

Comment: some clever caching? What if you change the name of your source file? is it slow again?

Comment: @RNJ, after the first slow run, changing both the input name and/or the output name have no effect on performance.  I update the input name in the file system and change the String value in code and the execution time is the same.  If there is caching happening it is very smart.  I included the code hoping someone else could run it and figure out what exactly is causing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key there is "first time". Your OS has cached the entire file in RAM (372MB isn't much these days), and so the only overhead is the time required to flip the zero-copy buffers through the memory-mapped space. If you flush the cache (don't know how to do that on Windows; if the file's on an external drive, you could unplug and replug), you'll see that settle down to read rates, and if you force the OS to flush the writes, your program will block for 10 seconds or so if you have a hard disk.

Comment: it's interesting that the bytes aren't actually written to disk and will only do so if the writes are flushed.  is there then no guarantee that the data is available on the file system after the program exits?

Comment: +1 MemoryMapped files have a force() method.  Once the data is in disk cache you are testing your memory to memory copy speed with some file system overhead.

Comment: @haventchecked When writes are guaranteed to have been committed is OS-dependent. POSIX systems use `fflush(3)` for this; I have no idea about Windows.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Probably not even memory-to-memory copy if Windows has a decent zero-copy I/O subsystem. It'd only have to shuffle descriptors around.

Comment: @chrylis If it did you would get constant time for a file copy even if the file was not in disk cache.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Depends on the OS, but I'd expect a page fault when trying to read it when it's not cached.

Comment: @chrylis with transferTo(), you don't actually read it into the program so the OS copy just create a new file which is marked as a copy of the old one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that once the file has been read once, the OS caches it in order to speed up subsequent reads. In addition, a feature from NTFS called Single Instance Storage might also play a part, as described in Wikipedia:

> When there are several directories that have different but similar files, some of these files may have identical content. Single instance storage allows identical files to be merged to one file and create references to that merged file.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Single_Instance_Storage_.28SIS.29

I'm not really sure if this is what you're seeing, but it the only thing I can think of that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be about right in terms of buffered IO performance.... What's happening is that you are reading **and writing** the file to memory only, and then, in the background, the OS is 'flushing' the output file to disk. You are not measuring the time it takes to write the file to disk, just to memory.

You may want to try again (for educational purposes) with the DSYNC options set for when you open your FileOutputStreams using the new-to-Java7 [Files.newOutputStream(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29) with the [DSYNC OpenOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html).

This way the file will be written to disk at the same time as you write to the output stream. There will not be any in-memory caching of the output file.