# BufferedWriter with Path parameter and buffer size parameter

Tags: java, java-io

I know I can do this (with the corresponding try and catch of course)

```
Path path = Paths.get(outputFieLocation);
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

and this as well

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFieLocation), 5 * 1024);
```

Is there any way to set a buffer size using Path as a parameter?

Comment: the default bufferSize is 8192 characters, do you need it larger? this value should be enough for I/O operations and you should not have performance issues

Comment: how are you going to write the data?!

Comment: @csoroiu I am combining large log files 100MB to 500MB. I wanted to use at least 500 KB buffers.

Comment: @user2511414 can you be more specific, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: how are you going to use the `BufferedWrite?` what kind of data are you going to write? byte? String? Object?!

Comment: @user2511414 I am going to write strings into a file line by line.

Comment: if you are trying to combine files, why not using transferTo function? if you do not have to do some special logic, that fuction works faster.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622768/java-nio-transferto-seems-to-be-impossibly-fast

Comment: I would have my own `OutputStream`, where it contains a (n-length) byte array as buffer. it's not a hard work really.

Comment: 500K is ridiculously large for an I/O buffer. Keep cutting it in half until you notice an actual difference. I suspect that won't occur until you get below 64k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can use `path.toFile()` to turn a `Path` into an equivalent `File` object suitable for the constructor of `FileWriter`. Note that you should not use the `FileWriter` as it unfortunately does not allow to specify the `Charset`.

```
final File file = path.toFile();
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
   new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),"UTF-8"), bufferSize);
```

([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998905/java-bufferedwriter-object-with-utf-8))

If there is no specific reason to set a custom buffer size, use the `Files.new...` alternative, the JDK defaults are sensible.